# PHP eval code sandbox break

Tags: php, security

I noticed a heavily downvoted comment in here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php

```
function eval_syntax($code)
{
    $braces = 0;
    $inString = 0;

    // We need to know if braces are correctly balanced.
    // This is not trivial due to variable interpolation
    // which occurs in heredoc, backticked and double quoted strings
    foreach (token_get_all('<?php ' . $code) as $token)
    {
        if (is_array($token))
        {
            switch ($token[0])
            {
            case T_CURLY_OPEN:
            case T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES:
            case T_START_HEREDOC: ++$inString; break;
            case T_END_HEREDOC:   --$inString; break;
            }
        }
        else if ($inString & 1)
        {
            switch ($token)
            {
            case '`':
            case '"': --$inString; break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch ($token)
            {
            case '`':
            case '"': ++$inString; break;

            case '{': ++$braces; break;
            case '}':
                if ($inString) --$inString;
                else
                {
                    --$braces;
                    if ($braces < 0) return false;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If $braces is not zero, then we are sure that $code is broken.
    // We run it anyway in order to catch the error message and line number.

    // Else, if $braces are correctly balanced, then we can safely put
    // $code in a dead code sandbox to prevent its execution.
    // Note that without this sandbox, a function or class declaration inside
    // $code could throw a "Cannot redeclare" fatal error.

    echo "Braces: ".$braces."\r\n";
    $braces || $code = "if(0){{$code}\n}";

    if (false === eval($code)) {}
}

eval_syntax("file_put_contents('/home/yourname/Desktop/done.txt', 'OVERWRITTEN');");
```

I tried to bypass the code to maliciously execute user-input, but I couldn't. I wonder why it got downvoted.

As you can see if curly brackets are not matching, it doesn't add the `'if(0){' . $code . '}` and executes the user input with mismatching curly brackets which will throw exception and won't really run.

If curly brackets are a match, it calls the eval, but its inside a `if {0}` "sandbox". How can someone bypass this?

**I know eval is insecure, but I want to know what's the trick here. How can you bypass security of `if (0)` and braces check in the code above?**

You can try directly the code from php.net or my minified/edited version above. Point is proving that this code is not secure and user an execute arbitrary PHP Code

Comment: check this answer about eval: https://stackoverflow.com/a/951868/3541922

Comment: @MikeVelazco I know eval is completely insecure, but what's the trick here? How can someone bypass the security check in the code above?

Comment: It does not check the syntax either, it only checks broken braces, so it's useless.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You may have overlooked the `eval()` at the end.

Comment: @duskwuff nope, im testing it and im always getting Braces: 0 for valid and invalid code. Try it: `eval_syntax("if(){}");` shows as valid but its obviously not.

Comment: Is the point of the function not to validate its working php code but not execute it :/

Comment: the point of the code is to validate but not execute the PHP code, but I want to bypass its security and execute user input directly with eval

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Get the original code from PHP.net site comment and see if you can break it's jail and execute user input directly with the eval

Comment: You cant as `if (0){}` will never execute. But again its useless as it does not check all syntax errors lol

Comment: being useless is true, but I wan't to know if someone can somehow bypass it and execute arbitrary PHP codes. I tried to add " // { " as to imbalance the curly brackets so it won't add the if (0) check and call eval directly, but get_tokens call ruins it. Trying to find a way to prove its inscure

Comment: Since its using the same AST parser as php does, any tricking with the comments will fail. I've checked all possible {-s in the code, but couldn't spot any that was missed out.  Ref: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a7fe2570d3ce6915d4ea85c62c0f880ddc225ba7/Zend/zend_language_parser.y

Comment: @lintabá Exactly! I tried lots of methods to bypass it to execute an arbitrary user-input. So far nothing...

Comment: The rule of thumb is slate the hell out of `eval()` even if its used safely, like above because of `if (0) {}` that's the protection, remove that and it will be a different story.. people love to jump on the evil/eval bandwagon (its cheap to downvote on php.net), the same people who see a SQL injection and love to throw bobby drop tables comical comment, when they know you cant drop a table without using a multi query api. i've built many projects which have used eval without problems, even netflix use a "script engine" which eventually hits an eval mechanism of sorts lol..

Comment: @JohnDoes I've edited my comment (damn auto-submit by enter..)

Comment: I didn't write the code, I'm trying to prove its insecure, unless I get code execution, I can't make my point

Comment: @lintabá good thinking... do you see any other way of bypassing the code?

Comment: @JohnDoes I've tried the function declaration too, but that works only in js. So unfortunatelly nothing yet, otherwise I'd have sent an answer. But a negative result is also a result :)

Comment: @lintabá Thanks for sharing the update. I'm testing as well. Lets see who n find the answer first :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178276/php-eval-code-sandbox-break